# What is the maximum query length accepted for a PostgreSQL multi-valued SELECT query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, bulkinsert, postgresql-copy

The context is that I am writing a script to send load/insert query to a postgres server to insert rows into an existent table. I read many resources about the topic, about the approach to choose, between "COPY" and multi-valued SELECT query. I want to know what is the maximum query length accepted for a PostgreSQL multi-valued SELECT query ? I am building a SQL query dynamically to send it to the postgres server, and I can't know beforehand how many line after "values" I may have.

Another question, if I store my table in a file and use "COPY" to load the file content, is there any  limit for the file, ie. limit in term of lines, bytes, ... ?

I tried both approaches, with the multi-valued SELECT query and the "COPY" query. They both work for me, but I need to know more about the limits of each one of them. I searched for it, I found that for a simple query the limit is 1GB. Is this limit applied to a multi-valued select ?

I couldn't find any limits for the "COPY" query, so I am looking for this information too.

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT :**

What I meant by "multi-valued select" query is :

```
SELECT INTO "TABLE" VALUES (Column 1, Column 2), (Column 1, Column 2), (Column 1, Column 2).. ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximal message length that the PostgreSQL frontend/backend protocol supports is 1GB. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-overview.html#PROTOCOL-MESSAGE-CONCEPTS) says:

> The first byte of a message identifies the message type, and the next four bytes specify the length of the rest of the message (this length count includes itself, but not the message-type byte).

But you are likely to get into trouble before you reach that limit.

If you intend to load lots of data into PostgreSQL, don't even consider using a multi-line `INSERT` statement. The way to go for that is `COPY`. With `COPY ... FROM STDIN`, you can load arbitrarily many data in a single statement, since you can send the data over the network in chunks. With `COPY ... FROM 'file'`, there is no limit on the size of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I understand from your answer, there is a limit even for the "COPY" query if I don't send data in chunks ?  if I store my data into a file which we suppose has a size higher than 1GB, and execute the "COPY" query on this file, will I encounter troubles ?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I was talking about `COPY FROM STDIN`, where you send the data from the client to the server. There is no limit to the amount of data, just a limit on how much you can send in a single message. There is no size limit with `COPY FROM 'file'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  I appreciate it, that's very clear !